# Does not work when use ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard

The logcat is below. what is wrong?

> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130): Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: illegal type variable reference
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForVariable.resolve(ImplForVariable.java:113)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForVariable.getGenericDeclaration(ImplForVariable.java:127)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForVariable.hashCode(ImplForVariable.java:46)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:1260)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$ParameterizedTypeImpl.hashCode(SourceFile:475)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.(SourceFile:64)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at com.gaozhi.wh.asynctask.MyAsyncTask$2$1.(SourceFile:78)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at com.gaozhi.wh.asynctask.MyAsyncTask$2.call(SourceFile:78)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at com.gaozhi.wh.asynctask.MyAsyncTask$2.call(SourceFile:1)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at com.gaozhi.wh.utils.async.AsyncTaskUtils$2.doInBackground(SourceFile:114)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at com.gaozhi.wh.utils.async.AsyncTaskUtils$2.doInBackground(SourceFile:1)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
> 07-24 10:54:13.529: E/AndroidRuntime(12130):  ... 4 more

I found that is caused by this line of code error

`info = GsonUtils.getMutileBean(result,new TypeToken<JsonResult<T>>() {}.getType());`

```
public static <T> T getMutileBean(String jsonData, Type type)
        throws Exception {
    return new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, type);
}
```

.

But I had add proguard configuration for Gson

> # Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields.  Proguard
>
> # removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
>
> -keepattributes Signature
>
> # For using GSON @Expose annotation
>
> -keepattributes *Annotation*
>
> # Gson specific classes
>
> -keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
>
> #-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
>
> # Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
>
> -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

Comment: How do You use reflection in your AsyncTask? Maybe reflecting classes are missed from proguard.cfg ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may need to add

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: I still have this error, any help here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198040/proguard-is-ruining-my-cleanliness-gson-and-generics

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `EnclosingMethod` to proguard config did not help me.

However by keeping the attribute `InnerClasses`, I was able to build a properly functioning APK